# How to add tags to a elastic ip with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

How is it possible to add tags with ansible to an allocated elastic ip. There are no Information in the official documentation:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_eip_module.html

The example code would be the following:

```
- name: provision new instances with ec2
  ec2:
    keypair: mykey
    instance_type: c1.medium
    image: ami-40603AD1
    wait: yes
    group: webserver
    count: 3
  register: ec2

- name: associate new elastic IPs with each of the instances
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ec2.instance_ids }}"
```

If I add a tags field then the following error is thrown:

> failed: [localhost] (item=i-08d2c1fee9eef9001) => {"ansible_loop_var":
>   "item", "changed": false, "item": "i-08d2c1fee9eef9001", "msg":
>   "Unsupported parameters for (ec2_eip) module: tags Supported
>   parameters include: allow_reassociation, aws_access_key,
>   aws_secret_key, debug_botocore_endpoint_logs, device_id, ec2_url,
>   in_vpc, private_ip_address, profile, public_ip, region,
>   release_on_disassociation, reuse_existing_ip_allowed, security_token,
>   state, validate_certs, wait_timeout"}

Comment: You can have a look at the ec2_tag module, it is used to tag AWS resources. Try this one. [Link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_tag_module.html)

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav can you please give an example how the `ec2_tag` module can be applied with `ec2_eip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ec2_tag module to tag EC2 resources.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_tag_module.html#ec2-tag-module

```
- name: associate new elastic IP with instance
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: "{{ l_ec2_instance_id }}"
  register: l_eip_register

- name: tag the elastic IP
  ec2_tag:
    resource: "{{ l_eip_register.allocation_id }}"
    tags:
      Name: webserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/55190 I don't think it's currently possible to tag EIPs using ansible modules.

Comment: please provide some additional data about the content of the linked resource as this link might stop working in the future...